# How to convert list to JSVal?

Tags: haskell, ghcjs

I'm trying to build JS FFI for some JS library to get it work with GHCJS and I need to convert list to single JSVal

```
listToJSVal :: PToJSVal a => [a] -> JSVal
listToJSVal = map pToJSVal
```

but get error

```
 Couldn't match type ‘[JSVal]’ with ‘JSVal’
    Expected type: [a] -> JSVal
      Actual type: [a] -> [JSVal]
```

obviously, I need concat function, but using `mconcat` gives

```
Could not deduce (Monoid JSVal) arising from a use of ‘mconcat’
    from the context (PToJSVal a)
      bound by the type signature for
```

Maybe, there is easier way how to do this conversion properly?

Answer (score 2):

Also you could convert it at hand:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import GHCJS.Marshal.Pure
import GHCJS.Types
import GHCJS.Foreign.QQ 
import GHCJS.Prim

listToJSVal :: PToJSVal a => [a] -> JSVal
listToJSVal xs = foldl push ar xs 
    where ar = [js'| [] |]
          push as x = [js'| { `as.push(`x); $r = `as } |]

printArray :: JSVal -> IO ()
printArray as = [js_| for(i = 0;i < `as.length;i++) { console.log(`as[i]) } |]

main = do 
     printArray $ listToJSVal ([1,2,3,4,5]::[Int])
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `pToJSVal` is only defined for base types.

For conversion of arbitrary values to JS, I would try the `toJSVal` and `toJSValListOf` functions defined in GHCJS/Marshal/Internal.hs [(link)](https://github.com/ghcjs/ghcjs-base/blob/831bbe58540158146c3f9b4e2fa960d82b11a1b6/GHCJS/Marshal/Internal.hs#L49-L59)

Comment: I tried those, but it use `IO`, but I have pure code and bringing IO will break all my pipeline

Comment: @Sigrlami this looks like an ok situation for unsafePerformIO ?